# ExpatParser$ParseException when parsing a remote xml file using SAX parser in android

Tags: android, parsing, sax

I am using sax parse for retrieving data and I am getting an error like this in `AsyncTask`:

```
org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 1615: not well-formed (invalid token)
org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseFragment(ExpatParser.java:515)
org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:474)
org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:321)
org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:279)
```

And here my code:

```
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    try {
                URL rssUrl = new URL(
                        "http://www.google.co.in xxxxxxxx.in");
                SAXParserFactory mySAXParserFactory = SAXParserFactory
                        .newInstance();
                SAXParser mySAXParser = mySAXParserFactory.newSAXParser();
                XMLReader myXMLReader = mySAXParser.getXMLReader();
                HanldlerImple myRSSHandler = new HanldlerImple();
                myXMLReader.setContentHandler(myRSSHandler);
                InputSource myInputSource = new InputSource(rssUrl.openStream());
                myXMLReader.parse(myInputSource);
                data=myRSSHandler.getdetaillist();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            return null;
        }
```

But when I pass to the parse method the `inputStream` instead of `inputSource` it parses the XML file but still has a problem with `telugu,tamil` characters between